# Process terminated, but its network resource remained

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking

My program has a TCP server and always has several longlived connections. Sometimes I close the program without closing all the connections and then I execute `netstat -ano` in command line, amazingly all the connections remained with the state of "ESTABLISHED" with a pid that doesn't exist in the task-manager! Restarting the network card doesn't do any help. The only solution is logout/logon or restarting the computer. Anybody ever met this problem?

Comment: Your program should contain clean-up code that closes the connections when it exits.

Comment: Are you sure logging out the user closes these connections?  That seems odd, I wasn't aware that Windows TCP associates connections with logon sessions.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the sockets in a 'half-closed' state.

They usually disappear after some timeout which may be pretty big (from 5 to 30 minutes), depending on your system.